# Django Database Module

Tags: database, django, mysql-python, django-database

I am developing a system that will need to connect from a remote mysql database on the fly to do a specific task. To accomplish this, I am thinking to use Mysql-db module in python. Since the remote database is not part of the system itself I do not prefer to add it on the system core database settings (DATABASES settings.py). Is there a much better way to accomplish this aside from using Mysql-db module? Is there a built in django module that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQLdb is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

For working inside virtualenv you need to install

> pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5